# How to remove a shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to remove a shared preference created while registering my user in register activity
the code used to save the shared preference in RegisterActivity file is :

```
spf = getSharedPreferences(MyPref,0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=spf.edit();
    editor.putString(name, txtfullname.getText().toString()); //name is a key which will help to identify.. abhi tera name is null.. its jus a variable now no key identifying value in it..
    editor.putString(age, txtage.getText().toString());//same for other two i.e age and ph_no these must b string keys
    editor.putString(ph_no, txtmobileno.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(email, txtemailid.getText().toString());
    editor.putString(password, txtpasskey.getText().toString());
    if(radio1.isChecked())
    {
        flag="Male";
    }
    else
    {
        flag="Female";
    }
    editor.putString(gender,flag);
    editor.putString(spinner_text, spinnertext);
    editor.commit();
```

now i want to remove this preference saved above
and i am using this code in my another activity:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editoer = pref.edit();
        editoer.clear();
        editoer.commit();
        finish();
```

But i am not able to delete it this way , any suggestions what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting wrong preferences, your preference name is "MyPref" than you have to get than preference name and clear that preference, for ex:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MyPref,0);
Editor editoer = pref.edit();
editoer.clear();
editoer.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this code

SharedPreferences myPrefs =      
v.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MyPref,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace SP by ""

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=spf.edit();
    editor.putString(name, ""); //name is a key which will help to identify.. abhi tera name is null.. its jus a variable now no key identifying value in it..
    editor.putString(age, "");//same for other two i.e age and ph_no these must b string keys
    editor.putString(ph_no, "");
    editor.putString(email, "");
    editor.putString(password, "");
    editor.putString(gender,"");
    editor.putString(spinner_text,"");
    editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the SharedPreference.Editor object, you could **easily delete the key-pair value by calling the remove() method** with the key as argument.

```
editor.remove(String key);
editor.apply();
```